# Request header field cache-control is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

After a lot of search I unable to resolve this issue if someone let me know how to solve this issue I'll be very thankful.

I am sending AJAX request on third party URL so I unable to add custom headers in requested URL.

[image]

Comment: As the error is trying to tell you, you can't send that header.

Comment: @SLaksif I comment or delete the header that also cause the same issue.

Comment: Then read that error and do what it tells you to do.

Answer (score 2):

`Request header field Cache-Control is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers error means` that `Cache-Control` field of **HTTP request header** is not handled or allowed by ***server***. Remove `Cache-Control`field from the request header.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution:  Use a very simple server-side script that acts as a proxy to the web service. So instead of requesting AJAX from the remote site, you request it locally on your own domain through the proxy. The proxy itself has it's programming logic to send your request off to the remote site, gather the data, and then serve it back to you.

Another solution: Look into JSONP http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP which is a method to request data from a server on another domain.

Comment: jsonp give me issues in url. let me share that

Comment: https://trancloud.dsipscs.com/ProcessEMVTransaction?callback=jQuery11020460551057475185_1503592838782&{%22TStream%22:{%22Transaction%22:{%22MerchantID%22:%22003503902913105%22,%22OperatorID%22:%22TEST%22,%22TranCode%22:%22EMVSale%22,%22InvoiceNo%22:%22100%22,%22RefNo%22:%22100%22,%22SecureDevice%22:%22CloudEMV2%22,%22RecordNo%22:%22RecordNumberRequested%22,%22Frequency%22:%22OneTime%22,%22Amount%22:{%22Purchase%22:%221.25%22,%22Gratuity%22:%220.75%22},%22SequenceNo%22:%220010010010%22,%22TranDeviceID%22:%22P

Comment: I get like this. How to fix that?

Comment: You need to send a request to server to enable CORS. Or i don't think there is any other way, except for using JSONP.

    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");  
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
    header("Access-Control-Max-Age: 1000");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With, Content-
    Type, Origin, Cache-Control, Pragma, Authorization, Accept, Accept-
    Encoding");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT, POST, GET, OPTIONS,  
    DELETE");

Something like this through headers.

Comment: Any helping URL to send Proxy request? CURL or anything else?

Comment: I hope that helps you out.Good luck mate :-)